# Unit testing protocol extensions through structs in Swift 3

Tags: swift, unit-testing, dependency-injection, swift3, swift-protocols

Here's the protocol oriented code i have for which i am stuck with for writing unit tests.

```
protocol TestProtocol {
    func testOne()
    func testTwo()
}

extension TestProtocol {
    var testHelper: TestHelper {
        return TestHelper()
    }
    fileprivate func _one() {
        testHelper.one()
    }
    func one() {
        _one()
    }
    fileprivate func _two() {
        testHelper.two()
    }
    func two() {
        _two()
    }
}

struct TestHelper {
    var userDefaults: UserDefaults {
        return UserDefaults.standard
    }
    func one() {
        userDefaults.set("12223334444", forKey: "PhoneNumberWithCountryCode")
    }
    func two() {
        userDefaults.set("Mark", forKey: "UserName")
    }
}

class TestAboveCode { }

extension TestAboveCode: TestProtocol {
    func testOne() {
        _one()
    }
    func testTwo() {
        _two()
    }
}

class UseAboveCode {
    func use() {
        TestAboveCode().testOne()
    }
}
```

here's the problem, 
To write unit test for UseAboveCode class, i need to mock the TestHelper struct. Though i can create a mock struct and override the existing functions, i cannot set the testHelper property in the TestProtocol extension. Is there a work around for this?

I do know the other approach which is making the TestHelper struct implement a protocol and ultimately injecting that as a property or through a constructor. This code above looks ideal for readability and usability but someone i am not able to wrap my head around unit test.

Am i over thinking with this approach? Please let me know what the best approach is.